# bash source script.sh with exit 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, source

I use a lot of external files in my scripts.

But I have a problem, that if I source a file with `exit` in the contents of the file, the script exits from loading and the strings that I want to use are gone
.

Example `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear;
source /opt/external-svn/config.sh;
echo "$var1 and $var2 and $var3";
```

Example `config.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="foo bar is great"
var2="foooo baar is greater"
var3="foooooooo baaaaaar is \
to long"

exit 0
```

Problem is the multiline `var3`,
so I want to use source
for `var1` and `var2`. The following is possible but not nice:

```
var1=$(cat "/opt/external-svn/config.sh" |awk -F'"' '/^var1/ {print $2}');
```

This is only work for single line not for `var3`.

Is there a simple / easy solution ?

**update because I'm to stupid to make a correct answer**

@Gilles
no not working the 
file in raw is here for suggestions 
[raw.githubusercontent.com/gorgone/temptest/master/config.sh](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/gorgone/temptest/master/config.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/tmp/$(basename $0).$$.tmp"
configsh="/opt/external-svn/config.sh"
grep -vE '^exit' $configsh > $TFILE
source "$TFILE"
```

exit the mainscript and got echo to screen

@Anthon it's also not working for the my file on github

**Update2 found solution**

i found the magic ONE 
i use the idea but its not a generic solution

**only for my special case**

```
cat config.sh |sed 's/if [ $# = 0 ]/if [ $# = 1 ]/g' >config.source
```

so i can source the file

**but the best way is to have a generic solution for all files**

Comment: Any reason why can't just filter each of the files to `/tmp/xyz` (dropping any exit lines and then source the result?

Comment: hmh not a bad idea i have also a fallback with wget to string there i can also sed all exits ... il try it ... I thought there is a cheat for source "skip ignore" or force read   ... but if it works im happy

Comment: Is it possible to just remove the `exit` statements?  If not, could you refactor your scripts so they both source the definitions from a common file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `abc.inc`:

```
x=1
exit 0
```

and `klm.inc`:

```
y=2
exit 0
```

then if you have `combine` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fn in abc klm; do
  grep -vE '^exit' $fn.inc > /tmp/xyz.tmp
  source /tmp/xyz.tmp
done

echo x: $x
echo y: $y
```

you can run `combine` and get as output:

```
x: 1
y: 2
```

This assumes that your `exit` statement are at the beginning of their lines, you might have to adjust the `grep` if they are not

Comment: If this solves your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.

Comment: update first post

Comment: @GorgoneImpertinence I don't understand your comment

Comment: update 2 in post 1

Answer (score 4):

You may override `exit` in your `main.sh` by declaring a custom `exit` function at the beginning of `main.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# main.sh
exit() { 
   local exit_code="${1-?}"
   test "$exit_code" -ne 0 && builtin exit "$exit_code"
   :
}
clear;
source /opt/external-svn/config.sh;
echo "$var1 and $var2 and $var3";

#unset -f exit; exit 0
builtin exit 0
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `"$1"` instead of `"$?"`...?

Comment: @Gilles update in first post code formatting in answer not working for my stupid brain